# Path of CSS files in Symfony2 for Twig rendering

Tags: css, symfony, twig

**Problem**

I need to generate CSS file while page is rendering (custom colors for each user). In order to achieve that I made an action to render the file and and put the route as a reference, like that:

```
public function styleAction()
{
    $backgroundColor = $this->getUser()->getCompany()->getBackgroundColor();
    if(!$backgroundColor || $backgroundColor =="")
        $backgroundColor = '#b5dea2';

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($this->render('*WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE*:style.css.twig',array('backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor)));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    return $response;
}
```

Route:

```
css_route:
    path: /css/mainStyle
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMainBundle:Default:style }
```

Question:
What to write in place of "WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE" in order to access to the file located under /web/css/style.css.twig.

Comment: same as other twig redered by a controller (no difference in this case) so `Resources\views\Default\style.css.twig`. Hope this help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file in your Bundles Resources\views directory.

Comment: Yeah but this not an appropriate way to do it. Is there any chance to access them without moving the files?

Comment: That's is the best practice way. All resources should live in bundles. templates and public js and css files.